# Not showing Dialog when opening file in Acrobat Pro using Applescript

Tags: macos, adobe, applescript, acrobat

When opening Adobe Acrobat Pro, whether it be through **Applescript** or finder, the introductory dialog is shown.  Is there a way to not show this dialog without already having checked the "Don't Show Again" option when opening a document using **Applescript**?

Photoshop and Illustrator **Applescript** libraries have ways of setting interaction levels and not showing dialogs, but I can't seem to find the option in Acrobat.

Comment: This can probably be done using JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Copy any applicable preferences files in ~/Library/Preferences from a machine that you have checked "Don't show again" on.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not in the dictionary, probably not.